# Is there a way to subdivide dates into smaller segments on the x axis?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I'm working on a school project and I have been trying to solve this for some time now but I cant find a solution to this.

[image]

The problem is whenever I run this the x axis is full with too many variables. I found a post similar to this but that post is working with normal variables not with date time variables (%Y/%m) like I am, witch creates problems when I try and run code like this one:

```
"scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 5))"
```

Keep in mind I have many rows, I don't know if that can cause problems but:

[image]

And the code:

```
plottest1 <- function(St, na){


  test1 <- ggplot(data = KunskiDepozit1, aes(x=Datum, y=St, group = 1)) +
    geom_line() + labs(x = "Datum", y = na, title = paste("vizualization ", na)) + geom_point()


  test1 <- test1 +
    theme_update(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


  return(test1)
}
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to add sample data, **Not images or links to images**

Comment: You need to change `Datum` to date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Geosopher and PoGibas have noted you need to make sure ggplot understands that Datum is a date. You may want to consider the package `lubridate`.

If I squint, I think your date information is in one column as YYYY-MM, so, to achieve that, you merely need something like:

```r
date_df <- existing_df %>%
    mutate(Datum = paste0(Datum, "-01")) %>%
    mutate(Datum = lubridate::ymd(Datum))
```

I have extracted the following sample code from the chapter on `lubridate` of [R for Data Science (freely available online)](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html) which explains how to do it when your date and time elements are split in various columns, using the function `lubridate::make_datetime`. It also shows that you can plot a date-time variable directly and ggplot will do the right thing.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(nycflights13) # Dataset with flight details

# Custom function to transform the date and time information from several columns
# into one "date-time" column. You may be able to get away simply with make_datetime

make_datetime_100 <- function(year, month, day, time) {
  make_datetime(year, month, day, time %/% 100, time %% 100)
}

# Apply that function to relevant columns in the dataset
flights_dt <- flights %>% 
  filter(!is.na(dep_time), !is.na(arr_time)) %>% 
  mutate(
    dep_time = make_datetime_100(year, month, day, dep_time),
    arr_time = make_datetime_100(year, month, day, arr_time),
    sched_dep_time = make_datetime_100(year, month, day, sched_dep_time),
    sched_arr_time = make_datetime_100(year, month, day, sched_arr_time)
  ) %>% 
  select(origin, dest, ends_with("delay"), ends_with("time"))


# Plot the dataset
flights_dt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dep_time)) + 
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 86400) # 86400 seconds = 1 day
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your x axis is a date I would try using an actual date axis instead of a discrete axis. Maybe play around with something like:

```
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 weeks")
```

Check out the ggplot2 scale documentation for the details!

```
?ggplot2::scale_x_date()
```